# how to make tab on top in ionic framework + angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

could you please tell me how to make tab on top in ionic framework + angular.?I am able to make in **jquery mobile** 
https://jsfiddle.net/j14u1kLx/
I need to try same on ionic framework

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTabs/
but these tab come on fotter I need to add tab on header I did in fiddle .could you please tel me how I will do in ionic same task .I am able to do using jquery mobile.

```
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one" data-ajax="false">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">two</a></li>
      <li><a href="ajax-content.html" data-ajax="false">three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
    <h1>First tab contents</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#striped-style-tabs

Comment: @user there is space on header could you please check http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEGRqO

Comment: There is a <div class ="tabs"> from css remove position: abolute, then it will be ok

Comment: or make it <div class="tabs" style="position:inherit">

Comment: Thanks @user...Last help .http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEGRqO

Comment: Is this the one you wanted?

Comment: yes @user thanks .But one more help can we show something on tab click in any tab click event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74564/discussion-between-user944513-and-user).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74622/discussion-between-user944513-and-reena).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this link:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#striped-style-tabs.

In order to make the header appears in top, there is a  you could either remove the css style "position: abolute" of this class  from the css file otherwise make it "position: inherit".
This will solve the purpose.